# Command Line Argument Counting

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

This is a simple C program that prints the number of command line argument passed to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
}
```

When I give the input

```
file_name *
```

It prints 623 instead of 2 in my pc (operating system Windows 7). But it gives the correct output in other cases. Is `*` a reserved character for command line arguments?
Note this program gives correct output for the following input:

```
file_name *Rafi
```

Output = 2

Comment: @pmg: I've modified the question so that 'file_name' is one word rather than two...which is probably what Rafi intended.  If not, he'll re-edit and we can cast doubts on 2 vs 3 once more.

Comment: Microsoft's C/C++ compiler (`cl.exe`) will print 2 in both your examples. Are you using a different compiler?

Comment: Yah.. you are right :) @Jonathan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On a Unix command line, the shell is responsible for handling wildcards. `yourapp *` will run `yourapp`, and pass the name of ALL of the non-hidden files in the current directory as arguments. In your case, that's 622 files (623 = 622 files + name of the program).

On Windows, applications are responsible for wildcard parsing, so argc is 2, 1 for the name of the program (argv[0]) and 1 for the wildcard (argv[1] = *);

Comment: Thank you :) I was thinking that 623 is nothing but an error :)

Comment: @Brian: it's not 'wrong', just different. Windows' style makes things like `ren *.jpg *.jpeg` possible, whereas that's v.difficult on a unix system.

Comment: What's so difficult about "for f in *.jpg; do mv $f `echo $f | cut -d'.' -f1`.jpeg; done" aside from it not working when there are multiple "." characters the filename?  (actually that's a pretty good example of how the Window's way has advantages too).

Comment: @William: yeah, that's handy, but that's a perl script, not a shell thing. With shell-only, a for loop is the only practical method of duplicating what windows does in a single command.

Comment: @MarcB: on Windows, REN is a 'command', is it not?  So executing a command on Unix would simply require enclosing the names in quotes: `/usr/bin/ren '*.jpg' '*.jpeg'` could be written, and could do what people want - but I agree it is not The Unix Way™ and people _would_ forget the quotes sometimes and be befuddled and/or discombobulated (unless the `ren` command were written to reject more than two user arguments (argc > 3), or reject it when the two arguments did not both include a single `*` metacharacter).

Comment: @Jonathan: ren's built into cmd.exe/command.com, so while it is a command, it's also not the same as running a full blown executable.

Answer (score 3):

That `*` gets expanded by the shell or the runtime library (the former on *nixes, the latter on Windowses), and instead of literal `*` you get the names of all the files in the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you're getting the 'shell wildcard expansion' or 'globbing' where the `*` is used as a wildcard to match file names to place in the `argv` array.

On Unix systems this is performed by the shell and has nothing (or little) to do with the C runtime.

On Windows systems, this functionality is not performed by the shell (unless possibly if you're using some Unix-like shell replacement like Cygwin).  The globbing functionality may or may not be performed by the C runtime's initialization depending on what tools and/or linker options you use:

- if you're using Microsoft's compiler, the C runtime will not perform globbing by default, and you would get an `argc` value of 2 in your example.  However, if you ask the linker to link in `setargv.obj` (or `wsetargv.obj` if you have a Unicode build), then globbing is added to the runtime initialization and you'll get behavior similar to Unix's.  `setargv.obj` has been distributed with MSVC for as long as I can remember, but it's still little known. I believe that most Windows programs perform their own wildcard expansion.
- if you're using the MinGW/GCC tool chain, the C runtime will perform globbing before calling `main()` (at least it does for MinGW 4.6.1 - I suspect it's been in MinGW for a long time). I think MinGW might not perform globbing for GUI programs.  You can disable MinGW's globbing behavior with one of the following:

  1. define a global variable named `_CRT_glob` and initialize it to `0`:

     ```
     int _CRT_glob = 0;
     ```
  2. link in the `lib/CRT_noglob.o` object file (I think this might be order dependent - you may need to place it before any libraries):

     ```
     gcc c:/mingw/lib/CRT_noglob.o main.o -o main.exe
     ```

Comment: An awesome piece of information w.r.t. `setargv.obj`, very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the shell expands `*` into all the file names (that don't start with a `.`) in the current directory.  This is all about the shell and very little to do with the C program.

The value of `argc` includes 1 for the program's own name, plus one for each argument passed by the shell.

Try:

```
filename *
filename '*'
```

The first will give you 623 (give or take - but it is time you cleaned up that directory!).  The second will give you 2.